# Did the ACLU prepare a lawsuit against The Young Women's Leadership School of East Harlem for gender discrimination?

Tags: united-states, education, school

The Young Women's Leadership School of East Harlem, formerly known as the The Young Women's Leadership Academy, is an all-girls charter school in Manhattan. The school's [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Women%27s_Leadership_School_of_East_Harlem) contains an interesting statement:

> While the American Civil Liberties Union prepared to sue [the school], it couldn't find a boy who wanted to attend it.

Wikipedia cites the following news article as a reference: https://www.amny.com/news/charter-school-will-be-a-first-for-girls/. However, this article contains only a single sentence about the ACLU, and no additional information:

> When Young Women’s Leadership Academy opened, the American Civil Liberties Union readied a legal challenge, saying it discriminated against boys, but was unable to find a boy who wanted to attend the school.

I'd like to learn more about this potential legal challenge. However, I cannot find any additional information about it, and I'm starting to wonder whether it actually happened.

Did the ACLU ever prepare a legal challenge to The Young Women's Leadership School of East Harlem for gender discrimination, but drop the effort because they were unable to find a boy who wished to attend the school?

Comment: I found a [WaPo article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/local/education/aclu-fights-dc-on-its-all-male-high-schools-admission-policy/2016/09/12/0c21d01c-7902-11e6-beac-57a4a412e93a_story.html) about the exact same situation, but with sexes reversed.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The ACLU did not. A state-level affiliate of the ACLU, the [New York Civil Liberties Union (NYCLU)](https://www.nyclu.org/about-nyclu), did.

[From an article written by Michael Meyers, who was involved with the NYCLU action against the charter school:](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/after-19year-probe-feds-k_b_8443130)

> We had preferred but couldn't file a lawsuit because no boy presented himself as a plaintiff for admission to the Young Women's Leadership School. As I kept telling anyone who would inquire: no boy wanted handed to him upon graduation a diploma that read that he was a proud alumnus of the Young Women's Leadership School. The YWLS' very name represented an attack on Title IX's equal protection principles.

It was a legal challenge under Title IX, because the charter school was accepting public funding for students, and was therefore not permitted to discriminate based on gender (unlike a private school).

My understanding is that Title IX was amended in 2006 to [explicitly allow for single-sex public & charter schools in certain situations](https://www2.ed.gov/about/offices/list/ocr/docs/t9-rel-exempt/index.html), and permits single-sex schools as follows:

> A public school district therefore may offer a nonvocational
> single-sex school so long as it provides a substantially equal school
> to students of the excluded sex. All other programs and activities of
> public schools (including single-sex schools) are governed by Title IX
> if the school district receives any Federal financial assistance.
>
> Public elementary and secondary schools are also subject to the sex
> discrimination prohibitions of the Equal Protection Clause of the U.S.
> Constitution and the requirements of the Equal Educational
> Opportunities Act of 1974.

The challenge that the NYCLU raised in 1996 would no longer apply today.

Comment: The NYCLU is the New York affiliate of the ACLU (they have one in every state, I believe), so I don't think it's too wrong to attribute the action to "the ACLU".

Comment: It took me embarrassingly long to realize that "preferred" in the first quote is likely a typo for "prepared". (As in, it's a typo in the original article, not a misquote.)

Comment: It would be helpful if the quote had "[sic]" to indicate this.

Comment: So this statute explicitly allows a "separate but equal" policy? Haven't we been there before?

Comment: @Barmar As the Equal Rights Amendment was defeated, there's no constitutional prohibition against sex or gender-based discrimination, just the Equal Protection Clause of the 14th amendment. FWIW the ACLU position is that this title IX amendment is bad: https://www.aclu.org/documents/sex-segregated-schools-separate-and-unequal

Comment: @Wowfunhappy: "Preferred" is not a typo, just a less familiar usage. See [definition 3 at Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prefer): "To present or submit (something) to an authority (now usually in 'to prefer charges')."

Comment: @NateEldredge: That is a correct meaning of the word but incompatible with the sentence quoted, which specifically says they *couldn't* submit it.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Perhaps "prefer" and "file" are talking about two different steps of the process.  Or maybe it is being used as a technical term that Wiktionary has oversimplified.

Comment: It's worth noting that the article contains other typos, for example "all of them ignored the local law that had been enacted in1991 to expressly bar a school from denying admission to anyone on account of her sex." (Unless I'm mistaken and "in1991" without a space is in fact also correct usage.)

Comment: Preferred isn't a typo, it's just bad writing. The context is that the NYCLU filed a challenge as a Title IX complaint with the DOE instead of a lawsuit, and "We had preferred (to file a lawsuit) but couldn't file a lawsuit because..."

Comment: I asked [a question on Law.SE about the terminology](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/93271/what-does-it-mean-to-prefer-a-lawsuit-and-how-is-it-different-from-filing).